# Why is GraphicsEnvironment headless?

Tags: java, fonts

I'm trying to register a .ttf Font using this method:

```
    private void addFont(String name) {
        try {
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            File file = new File("D:/Client/assets/fonts/"+ name);
            Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, file);
            ge.registerFont(font);
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Problem is that the fonts dont get created, all I get is:
`java.awt.FontFormatException: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException`

The exact same code worked on a past project, debugging with breakpoints I found that `ge` was a "Win32GraphicsEnvironment", meanwhile on the current project it's a HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment (may this be the problem?).

Upadate: With old/new project I mean two separate Minecraft versions that I'm modding (1.12.2 and 1.16.4), I'm running on a win 10 machine, debugging on Intellij Idea and using JDK 1.8 in both projects.

Comment: you shall update more details about the environment to avoid getting downvoted.
what means old vs new project? what was the previous runtime?

Comment: @cilap I edited the question a bit and added some environment infos, feel free to tell me if it's still unclear, I dont know what to add.

Comment: still unclear what old/new is. also what java version used in old/new?

Comment: @cilap okay, re-edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem, there was a static block with  this:

```
        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```

As said by @rmunge the solution was to just find it and set it to false.

```
        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
```

Answer (score 0):

please run your java process with

`java -Djava.awt.headless=true ...`

also try to add your font into the fonts folder of your JVM. If this works well you can try this
[Why does GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts() give different results when ssh'ed in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018848/why-does-graphicsenvironment-getlocalgraphicsenvironment-getallfonts-give-di)

Comment: Shouldn't it be -Djava.awt.headless=false or even more secure: make sure that the VM arguments do not contain any -Djava.awt.headless=true entry?

Comment: do you implemnt the server side or client side? for server you will require headless

Comment: It  doesn't matter whether you implement a server or a client. If you want to load .ttf Fonts in Java and you are running on Windows 10 you have to make sure that the VM arguments do NOT contain -Djava.awt.headless=true. Specifying this VM argument is the only way in Windows to get a HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment instead of a Win32GraphicsEnvironment.